# How to trigger the iframe to load in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a button that loads an iFrame. I would like to provide another button to open and load the iFrame in a new tab. Presently I hae the button to open essentially duplicate the page but not sure how to trigger the loading of the frame:

```
<button onclick="ViewFolder('f6f906a14')">Open cases below </button>    

<a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><button target="_blank">Open cases in a new tab</button></a>
    
<iframe id="postdicom-iframe" height="720" width="600"></iframe>
```

I tried to research some JS to load an iframe in a new tab. I found the tab would show the same page content on the new tab.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Many thanks,
Jack

```
var _apiKey = "68975ca0-58da-4fd8-8974-7614565466c";
var _accountKey = "1e072fb6-7805-4f1a-87dd-b5464564f5f7";
var _userUuid = "ee7e0713-1863-4913-b7da-6454364754da6";
var _folderUuid = "b5fb6b1c-c7ff-43b4-acef-4543554745d0";
////Send view request to PDAPI server and open it.
function ViewFolder(_folderUuid) {
    if (_accountKey && _apiKey) {
//Create a instance of PDCloudAPI object.
    var _cloudApi = new pDCloudApi(_apiKey, _accountKey);
    _cloudApi.Initialize(function (result) {
     if (result.Success) {
    console.log("API is initialized successfully.");
    console.log(result)
    _cloudApi.GetFolderViewUrl(_userUuid, _folderUuid, function (response) {
    console.error(response)
    if (response.Success) {
       var url = response.Result;
       var iframe = document.getElementById("pd-iframe");
       iframe.src = url;
        document.getElementById("iframe-container").style.display="block";
    }
    else {
    console.error(response.Message)
    }
     })
    }
     else {
       console.error("API initialize error.")
        console.error(result)
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                console.error("'_apiKey' or '_accountKey' are undefined.")
            }
        }

function HideIframe(){
    document.getElementById("iframe-container").style.display="none";
}
function openInNewTab(url) {
  window.open(url, '_blank').focus();
}
```

Comment: What contained within your iframe? Wouldn't it just be like opening a link in a new tab?

Comment: The iframe loads a console which uses an API to call medical images to be shown in a dedicated viewer.

Comment: What do you mean by "a console"? You should share the code for `ViewFolder()`.

Comment: by console I mean it loads an image viewer. I will add the code to my first post.

Comment: What exactly is an "image viewer? A browser can view an image; why do you need an iframe? You neglected to include all your `_cloudApi` so we can't recreate this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Reference: [Open a URL in a new tab using JavaScript](https://www.tutsplanet.com/open-url-new-tab-using-javascript/)

```
function openInNewTab(url) {
  window.open(url, '_blank').focus();
}

// Or just
window.open(url, '_blank').focus();

<div onclick="openInNewTab('www.test.com');">Something To Click On</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I am really new to Javascript. I have inserted the function. How should the link to the new tab look to load the iFrame?

Presently: <button onclick="ViewFolder('f6f906a14')">Open cases below </button>

Comment: @Jack - Can you please update a fiddle / Demo ? It will be really helpful